# Most sites seem to be down right now

Tags: support, status-completed, maintenance, downtime

Most sites seem to be down right now, e.g. Stack Overflow:

[image]

Meta Stack Exchange is one of the few which are still up (for me, located in the Netherlands). No updates on StackStatus ([Twitter](https://twitter.com/StackStatus) / [website](https://stackstatus.net/)).

Comment: And stackexchange.com is very slow to access

Comment: Related: janky CSS when the inbox popup fails to load

Comment: The only site that works for me is SE/MSE.  Tabs, rep counters, and inbox all don't work  on SE.

Comment: All the Meta sites work, though, for me.

Comment: @Ollie They run MSE off Taryn's desktop just in case

Comment: https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/1430166260965380096

Comment: We're investigating a widespread issue right now.

Comment: @Taryn Something which may be related is that, roughly around 16 hours ago, for a few minutes I had a similar experience to what Glorfindel wrote. In particular, only this Meta site seemed to be working, with 5 other sites I checked failing, with them display a message that the site was under maintenance. I also once got an "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" message on Mathematics, with it saying "Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified." As this was only for a short while & nobody else reported it, I didn't bother myself at that time.

Comment: @JohnOmielan We're aware of the issue yesterday as well, we've been digging on the problem trying to determine cause and then a fix for it

Comment: @Taryn, probably glitches caused by flooding and power failures in Jersey.

Comment: @Rob fortunately / unfortunately the issues are unrelated to Henri and the rain.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Sooooo, that sucked. I'm sorry! We've spent all day finding what happened here and finally figured out the interaction of things that took us offline and continued bouncing a bit. It only happens after another network/timeout failure itself occurs.

Ultimately, in an effort to increase reliability for people in higher latency and more network-interrupt-prone environments with StackExchange.Redis recently (e.g. cloud users), we created a worse problem for our high scale environment where sync-over-async is still present in some code paths. This manifests in very fun ways. [I did a detailed write up on the StackExchange.Redis repo](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1847), because that's where we'll need to fix it.

For the moment, I've de-listed the 2.2.62 release which doesn't *create* the issue, but exacerbates the issue at mass scale due to the way the task/pool pile-up behaves. We're [back on 2.2.50](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis/) while we figure out how to best solve all this better. We (hopefully obviously) didn't envision this combination of factors and how this spiral of death would manifest, but it's obvious in retrospect.

There's nothing to report here at the moment - we're back and stable. For the moment, it's back to the drawing board on making things better for other use cases. If anyone has ideas, feel free to put them on the GitHub issue!